# Adb commands from phone to the computer

Tags: android

i need a way to collect the adb commands log from my phone to the computer 
another way to explain it: i  need to know what adb commands is sent  to my android 
i tried this code but it didn't work:

```
adb kill-server
set ADB_TRACE=sockets
adb nodaemon server 2>&1 | for /f "usebackq tokens=7*" %a in (`findstr /c:"): '"`) do @echo %a %b >> %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\adb_host_log.txt
```

Comment: I don't know the answer (if there is one) but I'm curious why you would need to know that.

Comment: i work in smart phones field
and i have  Pc soft wares that doing a specified  tasks to the phones to repair it 
i need to know what adb commands they use in the process